# Face recognition in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pca

I am having an error, saying:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>
> ```
> Error in facerecognition (line 14) images(:, n) = img(:);
> ```

Can anyone help? The code I have written is below:

```
input_dir = 'D:\C.S\FYP\Matlab Projects\DIP Applications\Face recognition\Faces\';

image_dims = [48, 64];

filenames = dir(fullfile(input_dir, '*.jpg'));

num_images = numel(filenames);

images = [];

for n = 1:num_images

    filename = fullfile(input_dir, filenames(n).name);
    img = imread(filename);
    if n == 1
        images = zeros(prod(image_dims), num_images);
    end
    images(:, n) = img(:);
end

% steps 1 and 2: find the mean image and the mean-shifted input images

mean_face = mean(images, 2);

shifted_images = images - repmat(mean_face, 1, num_images);


% steps 3 and 4: calculate the ordered eigenvectors and eigenvalues

[evectors, score, evalues] = princomp(images');


% step 5: only retain the top 'num_eigenfaces' eigenvectors (i.e. the principal components)

num_eigenfaces = 20;

evectors = evectors(:, 1:num_eigenfaces);


% step 6: project the images into the subspace to generate the feature vectors

features = evectors' * shifted_images;


% calculate the similarity of the input to each training image

feature_vec = evectors' * (input_image(:) - mean_face);

similarity_score = arrayfun(@(n) 1 / (1 + norm(features(:,n) - feature_vec)), 1:num_images);


% find the image with the highest similarity

[match_score, match_ix] = max(similarity_score);


% display the result

figure, imshow([input_image reshape(images(:,match_ix), image_dims)]);

title(sprintf('matches %s, score %f', filenames(match_ix).name, match_score))
```

;

Comment: I am having an error, saying
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in facerecognition (line 14)
    images(:, n) = img(:);

Can any one help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error looks like it's being caused due to the inconsistent image dimensions that you specified at the beginning in comparison to the dimensions that are actually read in from the images you have in your directory.  What I would suggest you do is dynamically read in the image dimensions when you read in your first image.  BTW, this will **only** work if all of your images are the same dimensions in your directory.  Also, this is assuming all of your images are grayscale.  However, I can put code in place where if the images are not all the same size, and we can use the first image as the reference dimensions.  Should any image have dimensions that are unequal to the first image you read in, we'll resize the image so that it conforms to this size.

If you have any colour images, you'll want to convert them into grayscale first before running the code.  As such, modify your first `for` loop code (where you're reading in the images) to be like the following.  This is essentially your code, but anywhere that I have modified, you'll see a `%// NEW` statement beside each line of code that I have placed in:

```
image_dims = []; %// NEW - Set to this instead of [48,64]

for n = 1:num_images

    filename = fullfile(input_dir, filenames(n).name);
    img = imread(filename);
    if size(img,3) == 3 %// NEW - Convert to gray scale if necessary
        img = rgb2gray(img); %// Use rgb2gray if colour
    end
    if n == 1
        image_dims = size(img); %// NEW - Read in image dimensions here
        images = zeros(prod(image_dims), num_images);
    else
        %// NEW - If the image read in is not the same dimensions
        %// as the first image read in, resize the image accordingly
        if size(img,1) ~= image_dims(1) || size(img,2) ~= image_dims(2)
            img = imresize(img, image_dims, 'bilinear');
        end
    end

    images(:, n) = img(:);
end
```

Comment: I think previous problem is solved, thanks for that. Now I am having problem
'Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in facerecognition (line 32)
features = evectors * shifted_images;'

Comment: @Anonymous - You forgot a `'` character.  In your original code, `evectors` is transposed.  As such, do this: `features = evectors' * shifted_images;`.

Comment: @Anonymous - What is the size of `evectors` and `shifted_images`? Use `size` and print out both variables for me.  That multiplication is not working because the dimensions for the matrices are incompatible.

Comment: This is the size.
>>facerecognition
evectors 68, shifted_images 20
evectors 530432, shifted_images 68

Comment: @Anonymous - Ok, do this for me instead: `[rows1 cols1 dim1] = size(evectors) [rows2 cols2 dim2] = size(shifted_images)`.  Print out all of those variables then put them here.

Comment: Output:
rows1:68 cols1:20 dim1:1
rows2:530432 cols2:68 dim2:1

Comment: @Anonymous - Try transposing both `evectors` and `shifted_images` so that the matrix multiplication will work.  As such: `features = evectors' * shifted_images';`

Comment: @Anonymous - This'll be the last question I answer.  It's a matter of making sure the dimensions are consistent.  Use the debugger and step through your code one line at a time, printing out the dimensions of each variable that is produced.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the size of `images(:, n)` is not the same as the size of `img(:)`. You should put a breakpoint on that line, and figure out why that is.